# rails partial not found but it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin, partials

inb4 read the docs

I've already tried everything in the documentation and everything on stackoverflow just repeats the documentation.

I'm trying to render a partial from within another view inside a gem being used by the application:

```
<%= render :partial => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/views/layouts/login" %>
```

It's complaining that the partial isn't found even though I know it exists.

```
Missing partial /home/hstorres/src/<app-name>/app/views/layouts/login
```

The following command was done from within the app containing the partial:

```
$ ls /home/hstorres/src/<app-name>/app/views/layouts
application.html.erb _login.html.erb
```

So if it exists, and it's looking for it in the right place, why can't it find it?

Comment: So your partial is named `_login.html.erb` in `app/views/layouts`?? And would this not work?? `<%= render partial: "layouts/login" %>` because you are trying to render it from a gem?? Just trying to get a little more info on the problem.

Comment: Can I also recommend naming your app something other than "<app-name>"? The <> in the path may be messing with things.

Comment: Kori, I suspect Hugo just put that in his question to block the actual name of the app...

Comment: Good thing the people who answered after @Sanket decided not to read his answer, as all they have done is copy and pasted his answer. Really? Maybe someone should answer and use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @Justin I assumed that wouldn't work because I was hacking a file in a gem, without realizing that the gem gets loaded into the app anyways. And yes, I had to block out the name of the app just in case.

Comment: Yea I assumed that was your thought process. Glad you got it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/login" %>
```

Comment: I assumed that from within the gem it wouldn't work, which is stupid because the gem renders the view from the app, which is why I didn't even try doing it this way. Thank you.

Comment: :) This will also works <% render 'layouts/login' %> when you need to render partial no need to mention partial word but written partial word is more readable....

Comment: Yeah I know the different hash syntaxes I just had it that way because that's how it is in the rest of the code (it's not code that I originally wrote).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<%= render "layouts/login" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

View paths in Rails are relative to `/app/views/`.  Simply typing `render :partial => "layouts/login"` will do what you want.